# Need to include some more into a asked and answered question

Tags: support

I am not going to make it a discussion, but when I asked the question I was not having
correct idea of one e.g. usecase that I now want to include into this question
it already asked and answered.

If I am allowed to add some more into the question, then should I have to add it into
comment with question or should edit the original question to append some more.

If I am not allowed then I guess I have to ask it in separate question referencing the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would be to edit the question and add it as "Updates" in bold heading and then add your question.

If your edit is after seeing some comments, then you should probably update the question and also leave a comment saying "question updated after such and such comments from @.. "